# Zend Mail Exception - unroutable Address - why?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-mail

Hi guys I've built a simple cron program which runs in php using the zend framework. It sends emails periodically to members of a website with updates. It was working fine when all of a sudden it just dies out upon emailing to a particular email and all I get is this error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message 'Unrouteable address ' in /web/content/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php:431
```

Whats going on and why is this happening for this particular email?

The email seems fine though i.e it isn't malformed or so. Also how can I prevent something like this from stopping the cron job to proceed with other emails.

Answer (score 0):

What about placing it in a try catch block ?

Comment: Does that helps when you put in try catch ?

Comment: @Ali: It's the uncaught exception that is fatal. Eating the exception in the catch might at least allow the cron job to continue. Still probably a good idea to log it, though.

Comment: Yes David Weinraub is right . Log it to track why its happening .

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should validate email addresses, Afterwards you should try a catch block like this:

```
try {

                    /*
                     * Set up Testing environment for Smtp mail
                     * Handle Mail exceptions Different
                     */

                    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
                    $mail->send();




                } catch (Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception $ex) {
                    $this->addError('There was an error sending e-mail to the new admin !');
                } catch (Exception $ex) {
                    $this->addError('There was an error processing your request');
                }
```